# Firefox stops using a pinned icon on Windows 7 taskbar every time it is updated

Tags: windows-7, firefox

This had been asked several times on [Mozilla support site](http://support.mozilla.org):

- [Windows 7 - Firefox 5 pinned taskbar icon not utilizing pinned icon when opening Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/844131)
- [Firefox 10.0 now creates a new icon on Windows 7 Taskbar when launched. Why?](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/939075)

The problem is that all proposed solutions require some actions (unpin, then pin again) **every time Firefox is updated**.

It would not be a big problem if I did not use additional command line arguments for Firefox. Every time I repin the Firefox icon, the arguments are lost.

It would not be a big problem if Mozilla did not change the major version of Firefox so often. I have found the file which is responsible for Firefox icon:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Firefox.lnk
```

It turns out that this file contains some information either about Firefox version or its hashsum. So every time I update Firefox, Windows fails to match the new version with the old icon.

I am looking for a solution that would not require repetitive actions on each Firefox update, or at least would preserve the command line arguments I start Firefox with.

Comment: This is not the behaviour I get on Windows 7. Have you tried pinning the program by a different method to the one that you use? (Not exactly sure of the different methods, but you can look online). Also, there is Firefox ESR if you don't want to have to update Firefox too often (you only get important security updates for a long period of time before the larger version increment).

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: I don't understand you. Will I get a differect pinned icon by dragging a shortcut onto the taskbar instead of choosing "Pin" from the popup menu? What method did you use?

Who said I don't want to update Firefox? I am just confused how frequently Mozilla releases new major versions.

Comment: I am just suggesting a method that might resolve your issue. I personally did use the "Pin this program to taskbar" item. The suggestion of using Firefox ESR is to reduce the effect of this issue since less updates = less pinning hassle. The reason that Mozilla began the fast release schedule is to introduce new updates/features faster which would speed up the pace of advancement. I have a sneaking suspicion that Google Chrome's own fast release schedule was also a factor.

Comment: "This is not the behaviour I get on Windows 7" - My FF pinned icon does not disappear or otherwise require re-pinning either every time I update the browser, and I've been doing so since v3.x.

Comment: I confirm this is still happening every major update. Win 7 x64, two different machines, current FF is 58.0.2