# Updating Firefox causes two icons to appear in the taskbar in Windows 10

Tags: firefox, windows-10, taskbar

I am using Firefox version 44 on Windows 10. Whenever there is any update to Firefox, this will cause 2 icons on the taskbar whenever I open Firefox, like attached picture below:

[image]

Other than that, it will also create 2 different entries in "Programs and Features"

[image]

For some reason, the workaround to solve this is to unpin Firefox from the taskbar, rename Firefox folder to something else (i.e. Mozilla Firefox2), and pin Firefox again to the taskbar.

But I am looking for permanent solution to fix this. Any idea?

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/533111/firefox-stops-using-a-pinned-icon-on-windows-7-taskbar-every-time-it-is-updated

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Firefox and right click the opened window in the taskbar and choose "pin to this program taskbar". Delete the other icons. This should fix it. I had the same issue for iTunes

Comment: tried this before but it does not work